# How to fill an irregular polygon which has been drawn by mouse clicks?

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I am working on a java graphics project. So basically, i need to draw a shape on my `JPanel` using mouse clicks. I have to prompt the user for the border color which is working good but I don't know how to fill the irregular polygon.. I have prompted the user for choosing the shape color using `JColorChooser` but how to fill it?

I am trying to implement it in my `paintComponent` method.

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating what you have tried if you need more help.

Comment: vector or raster?

Answer (score 1):

> but i dont know how to fill the irregular polygon.

1. Create a `Polygon` object to represent the `Shape`.
2. Use the Graphics2D `draw(Shape)` method to paint the Shape outline and the `fill(Shape)` method to fill the Shape

Simple example:

```
Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
triangle.addPoint(0, 0);
triangle.addPoint(15, 30);
triangle.addPoint(30, 0);
g2d.setColor( Color.RED );
g2d.fill( triangle );
```

Comment: How can i use a triangle when the polygon has many more sides?

Comment: As I said the the "triangle" was a "simple" example. Why do you think you are limited to adding 3 points to the `Polygon`? You need at least 3 side to enclose the shape. If you want more sides then add more points.

Comment: Sorry am a beginner in this

Comment: I think you are not getting me. My polygon is drawn by mouse clicks, it can have as MANY sides as it can, like more than 20 sides. How will i fill such a shape?

Comment: *it can have as MANY sides ... like more than 20 sides.* - I already told you that you can add an number of Points to the Polygon. So the basic steps are: 1) you create an instance of the Polygon in your class where you do the custom painting. 2) In you MouseListener code when the mouse is clicked you add the mouse Point to the Polygon  and invoke repaint() 3) in the paintComponent(...) method you use the last two line of code I provided above to set the color and paint the Polygon. 4) It will either paint as you expect or it won't. I have no idea what a 20 sided Polygon should look like.

Comment: Note, you can also search the forum for examples that use the `Polygon` class. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating what you have tried if you need more help.

Comment: @0x12abc Since you haven't posted an [mre] the problem must be solved. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.